# Database design/MVC for two related tables in Visual Studio with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, visual-studio-community

I am new to database design and to MVC programming, so I am asking for advice with best practices on database design and how to solve a problem that my current structure is creating.

I have a database that keeps track of locations (to make it as simple as possible, think of something similar to Yelp). It contains two tables with the following fields:

- Location: LocationID, RestaurantType (which can be Italian, Japanese, etc.,), hours, ratings, and a lot of other details about the location (20+ fields).
- LocationContact: LocationContactID, Address, State, ZIP, URL, and the LocationID as a foreign key to find the rest of the details in the Location table.

Even though both refer to the same type of data, I split it in two tables because the application will mostly searching by location, so it will find the closest restaurants by looking at the LocationContact table (instead of having to go through a table with 30+ fields). Once a few are selected, it can give more details by finding the LocationID in the Location table.

First, I am wondering whether this is good design or whether I should have both together as one big Location table, if splitting them would not make any difference in efficience. This would solve the following coding problem I am running into.

The problem came when I generated the MVC code for CRUD operations within Visual Studio. The scaffolding code generated for Location allows me to create or delete a Location entry only, and I had to generate separate CRUD operations for LocationContact. As you can imagine, when entering a new location, both the details and contact information would need to be entered at the same time; same for deleting and updating. Currently I have to create an entry for Location, remember the LocationID, and then create a separate LocationContact entry with the LocationID as foreign key. Deleting also has to be done in two steps (first deleting LocationContact and then Location), which is very cumbersome.

Do I have to fix this manually (or, even worse, handle it through the controller), or can I tell Visual Studio that these two tables should be treated together? I am familiar with how Visual Studio treats lookup tables automatically, so I would like for it to do something similar here. I am also using the Entity Framework.

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Please let me know if something was not clear enough or if more details are needed. Thank you!

Comment: `LocationContact` whose information does it store ? The Location people or the Customer ?

Comment: LocationContact stores the Location (restaurant) address and URL. Location stores all other details about the restaurant (type of restaurant, ratings, etc.)

Comment: Well if it looks like one<-->one I don't see the point in splitting it. But then it's a choice.. As for the creating/edit ,one option is, you could create a combined model `MyLoacationModel` add these two EF generated Models to it. The "Generate View" probably wont do the scaffolding as required, but you can copy the existing ones and build the form to POST to `ActionResult Save(MyLoacationModel model)`. The only thing to watch out is if the validation of the model fails at Server, you will need to reconstruct some properties like `List<SelectListItem>` when sending back the `View(model)`.

Comment: That definitely helps. Thank you so much!